# Angular: Getting [filter:notarray] error while filtering array of objects

Tags: angularjs

I have an Array of students who are in the format of an array of objects. The list is returned by Angular $http Service.

When I test using angular.isArray it is confirmed to be an Array.

Using a filter of ng-repeat="student in students|filter:searchText" I get a [filter:notarray] error. The filter is working though.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry. Was messing with my Array by starting with $scope.students={}; in my Controller and then;
$scope.students=data; after the $http call.

Removing $scope.students={}; fixed the error.